# How to make the following plot?

Tags: plotting, charts

Consider the data in the form

```
data={{"proton",20},{"pi0",40},{"K0L",9},{"rho0",60}};
```

How to plot a figure similar to the one presented in the screenshot below? For the y axis, one may assume for simplicity just the value of the second column of the data.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen `BarChart`? (E.g. `BarChart[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 5, "d" -> 3|>, ChartLabels -> Automatic]`)

Comment: `BarChart[Last /@ data, ChartLabels -> (First /@ data), 
 ChartStyle -> ColorData[97][1]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BarChart[
 Last /@ data
 , LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Style[#, Red, 12], Above] &)
 , ChartLabels -> Placed[First /@ data, Below]
 , ChartStyle -> ColorData[97][1]
 , BarSpacing -> Small
 , Ticks -> {Transpose[{Last /@ data, Range@Length@data}], Automatic}
 , GridLines -> {Range@Length@data, 
   Range[0, Ceiling[Max[Last /@ data], 10], 10]}
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}
 , ImagePadding -> {{20, 0}, {20, 20}}
 ]
```

[image]